# Putting menu options in "more" button when there is not enough space

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am just starting with web developing so sorry if my questions are trivial.

I am using Bootstrap 4 and created `navbar` with hamburger menu which hides entire menu when screen reaches certain width but I would like to change that the single menu elements hides in "more" button one by one so that if only one menu option is too much for the menu to fit, only that option goes to "more" button.

First I tried in Javascript to tide screen width to make disappear last element :

```js
setInterval(okno, 25)

function okno() {
    var a = window.innerWidth;
    if (a < 1335) {
        document.getElementById("kontakt").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl navbar-light"
    style="background-color:dimgrey;position:fixed;width:100%;z-index:100">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" style="background:white;float:left !important" data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#colapsibleNavbar">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon" style="color:black !important"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="colapsibleNavbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="kopysno.html">Strona Główna</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="Aktualnosci.html">Aktualności</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="mapaokolicy.html">Mapa Okolicy</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" style="text-align:center;text-decoration:none" data-toggle="dropdown"
                        href="#">Informacje</a>
                    <div style="background-color:dimgrey" class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="Historia.html">Historia</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Geografia</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Środowisko</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Kartografia Archiwalna</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Galeria Fotografii</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Filmy</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="dawnimieszkancy.html">Dawni Mieszkańcy</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Artykuły prasowe</a>
            </li>
            <li class="kontakt nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

But it simply doesn't work and i don't know why. Can you help me? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have an element with `kontakt` ID, but you can find it by its className using `document.querySelector('.className')`.

Create the function and call it when DOM is loaded or window is resized, adding event listeners for each one:

```js
function okno() {
    if(window.innerWidth < 1335) {
         // Hide if window width is less than 1335
         document.querySelector(".kontakt").style.display = "none";
    } else {
         // Show if window with is greater or equal than 1335
         // Use empty string to set the default element display setting
         document.querySelector(".kontakt").style.display = "";
    }
}
// Call when DOM is loaded
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', okno);
// Call if window is resized
window.addEventListener('resize', okno);
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl navbar-light" style="background-color:dimgrey;position:fixed;width:100%;z-index:100">
                        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" style="background:white;float:left !important" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#colapsibleNavbar">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon" style="color:black !important"></span>
                        </button>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="colapsibleNavbar">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav" >
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="kopysno.html">Strona Główna</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="Aktualnosci.html">Aktualności</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="mapaokolicy.html">Mapa Okolicy</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <div class="dropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" style="text-align:center;text-decoration:none" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Informacje</a>
                                    <div style="background-color:dimgrey"class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="Historia.html">Historia</a>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Geografia</a>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Środowisko</a>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Kartografia Archiwalna</a>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Galeria Fotografii</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>  
                            </li>
                            
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Filmy</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="dawnimieszkancy.html">Dawni Mieszkańcy</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Artykuły prasowe</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="kontakt nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a>
                            </li>   
                        </ul>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. What a stupid mistake xD. Certainly that will stay in my memory for a long time.

Comment: There's no stupid mistakes, we always learn from them.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried a css script such as

```
  <style>
       #your_div{
           max-height: set the height you want here, like 150px;
       }
  </style>
```

then run a JavaScript code to check for div height, and if div height exceeds or is equal to, use .append to add a button that with

```
<button onclick="my_function()" value="Give Me More Content">
 <script>
      function my_function(){
           $.("#your_div").style("max-height", "1000px (this could be any number)");
      }
 </script>
```

Just an idea, but hope it helps

Comment: Interesting. I will try that